# why currenuser ID (firebase) is changing with receiver ID in my android chat app which makes problem in my Seen message function?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

i am working on my android chat app and i faced when i add Seen messages feature . So i am asking for two things and i hope i will find an answer .
we suppose than we have two users A and B , and i make Log.i to check `currentUserID` and `receiverID`.
when A send message1 to B here no problem , when i log out from A and login with B `isSeen` will be `true` only in firebase (here i think is a problem in adapter i let it later) , when i check the `currentUserID` and `receiverID` no problem , BUT when i Logout and o return to A who sent message1 to B and i try to send message2 here is the problem : i found the Log.i fro many times where some times `currentUserID = B's ID` and `receiverID=A's ID` which is wrong that way the `isSeen` will be equal to `true`. So i need to know why ID's are changing and why i found a lot of `Log.i` and what is the best algorithms (kotlin if you can, if not java) for Seen feature ?????

- i am calling `SeenMessage` function in the end of my `DiscussionActivity`
- my `SeenMessage` function :

  private fun seenMessage() {

  ```
    var chatss: List<ChatData> = arrayListOf()
    val chatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Chats")
    chatsRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                val chat = snapshot.getValue(ChatData::class.java)
                if (chat!!.sender == currentUserID && chat.receiver == receiverID
                    || chat.sender == receiverID && chat.receiver == currentUserID) {
                    (chatss as ArrayList<ChatData>).add(chat)
                }
            }
            val lastChat = chatss.last()
            Log.i("problem -_-", "$lastChat")
            Log.i("problem -_-", "DiscussionActivity currentUserID = $currentUserID")
            Log.i("problem -_-", "DiscussionActivity receiverID = $receiverID")

            if (lastChat.sender == receiverID && lastChat.receiver == currentUserID) {

                        val seenMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                        seenMap["isSeen"] = true
                        chatsRef.child(lastChat.messageId).updateChildren(seenMap)
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {   }
    })
  ```

[image: Log.i]

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App using Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this message seen function. it is in working state sir, and use this function in on Chat activity because when the chat activity is open then automatically it update the message as seen. `

```
    // message get seen function
private fun seenMessage(receiverId: String) {
    val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference(CHATS)
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val message = snapshot.getValue(Message::class.java)!!
                if (message.receiver.equals(currentUserId) && message.sender.equals( receiverId )) {
                    val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                    hashMap["isseen"] = true
                    snapshot.ref.updateChildren(hashMap)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}`
```

Comment: Thank's it worked , i think the problem is solved because of addListenerForSingleValueEvent , in my program i used addValueEventListener , so please can you explain the difference between them ?

Comment: addValueEventListener is automatically call it self every time when changing in a node and addListenerForSingleValueEvent is call only one time.